# What's the rush equivalent of npm audit fix?

Tags: npm, rush

What's the rush equivalent of npm audit fix? Rush runs behind the scenes npm, but doesn't have a package-lock, so when they tell me "run npm audit fix" I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rushjs with pnpm package manager then the command you are looking for is `rush-pnpm audit fix`.

And here is the rushstack issue ticket to support all by rush command
https://github.com/microsoft/rushstack/issues/3727